# Strange sorting with reversed using new API on Java8

Tags: java, collections

Java8 supports a new way to sort collections. That looks elegant at the first glance but I get stuck in a case where I found it rather confusing.

The case is to apply chained sorting attributes, that is ok. But when using reverse(), the whole comparator is reversed. This leads to a confusing calling sequence

For choosing ascending name and descending age the API-calls look like

```
 Comparator
   .comparing(Person::getName).reversed()
   .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed()
```

In words: compare on name descending, then compare on age ascending, and then reverse the whole comparator.

For me cases b) and c) looks strange and not intuitive.

**Is there a better and more readable and intuitive way to express multiple sorting with ascending/descending?**

I used the following code

the POJO

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person() {    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person(String name,  int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + '(' + age + ')';
    }
}
```

the test code

```
public class Sort { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("michael", 28),
            new Person("peter", 29),
            new Person("marion", 21),
            new Person("peter", 22),
            new Person("hanna", 24),
            new Person("hanna", 27),
            new Person("albert", 23));

        // a) ascending name and age
        Collections.sort(persons, Comparator
            .comparing(Person::getName)
            .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge));
        System.out.println(persons);

        // b) ascending name and descending age
        Collections.sort(persons, Comparator
            .comparing(Person::getName).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
        System.out.println(persons);

        // c) descending name and age
        Collections.sort(persons,  Comparator
            .comparing(Person::getName)
            .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
        System.out.println(persons);

        // d) descending name and ascending age
        Collections.sort(persons, Comparator
            .comparing(Person::getName).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge));
        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
```

the result list

```
[albert(23), hanna(24), hanna(27), marion(21), michael(28), peter(22), peter(29)]
[albert(23), hanna(27), hanna(24), marion(21), michael(28), peter(29), peter(22)]
[peter(29), peter(22), michael(28), marion(21), hanna(27), hanna(24), albert(23)]
[peter(22), peter(29), michael(28), marion(21), hanna(24), hanna(27), albert(23)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any complex expression, the simplest way is to split it into multiple ones to improve readability. In this case, you can simply do:

```
Comparator<Person> ascNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName);
Comparator<Person> descAgeComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed();

Comparator<Person> personComparator = ascNameComparator.thenComparing(descAgeComparator);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this (using static imports to make it more succinct btw):

```
Comparator<Person> ascNameDescAgeComp = 
   comparing(Person::getName)
   .thenComparing(comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
Collections.sort(persons, ascNameDescAgeComp );
```

Comment: More succinct: `persons.sort(ascNameDescAgeComp);`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use streams?

You can try something like this:

```
persons =  persons.stream().sorted( (p,op) -> p.getName().compareTo(op.getName()) + Integer.compare(op.getAge(),p.getAge())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am sorry, this code does not change the order in persons

Comment: of course not, but you can asign a new reference to persons